# Allowing tags in django-admin for a readonly field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

If I have a function defined in an admin class that I want to display as HTML, I give the function a property `function_name.allow_tags=True`. How can I do the same for a read-only field?

I can't do

```
property_name.allow_tags=True
```

in the admin, and in the model it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a function that returns the read-only field, hide the read-only field, and display tags on the function.